# Use own image as map and mark places using x,y coordinates in android

Tags: android, maps

I need to use my own image as a map and place markers (or a small flag-image) dynamically on the map at different positions (x,y coordinates or l,t,r,b parameters) on the map based on certain criteria. I am having problems implementing it with 'ImageView', 'ImageMap' & 'Drawable' and have searched all questions on stackoverflow. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to user Overlays for displaying images on a map. A very good tutorial is given in the official [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/).

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this for my very first app. Inside of my activity, I created a custom View class, where I overrode the onDraw method and drew my map image, flags, etc. This is the tutorial I used, I recommend you check it out: [Anddev.org](http://www.anddev.org/large_image_scrolling_using_low_level_touch_events-t11182.html) (you may not need to implement scrolling, but the rest of it should be relevant).

Alternatively, you can use the Google Maps API to display their map with Overlays but it doesn't sound like that's what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thank you..I did what you suggested.. but my overlays are not working on my custom image(which I've used as a map). Can you give me a direction for that..or an example